# 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer : Python error

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I was writing a function which will receive two lists of strings as arguments.
I need to check the number of times each string in the second list occurs in the first list and return an array of the counts. I thought of popping the found elements from the first array so that on the coming searches, I need to travel only lesser elements. But I am getting this error on `strings.pop(i)`.

```
def matchingStrings(strings, queries):
    a=[0 for i in range(len(queries))]
    j=0
    for i in queries :    
        while i in strings :
            a[j]=a[j]+1
            strings.pop(i)
        j=j+1
    return a
```

Comment: Kindly paste the data of strings and queries too. Couldn't debug it without knowing what kind of input you are passing as parameters.

Comment: @RafiqueMohammed Got it! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) that:

> `s.pop([i])` - retrieves the item at *i* and also removes it from *s*

So `i` is expected to be an index, and you're giving it a string. You might change to:

```
strings.pop(strings.index(i))
```

---

But that seems like an over-kill and also your attempt to make things more efficient by removing elements goes in vein because of the line:

```
while i in strings:
```

It might not be explicit, but this line loops the list every time. And even though you are making it shorter, it is alot.

One way to do it going over the list **only 1 time** is using a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```py
from collections import Counter

strings = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "apple", "banana"]
queries = ["apple", "orange", "potato"]

c = Counter(strings)
res = [c[q] for q in queries]
print(res)
```

Gives:

```
[2, 1, 0]
```